# python d20 dice rolling program

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming but I'm trying to make a program that is essentially rolling a 20 sided dice. I'm trying to make it so that the program will ask how many dice the user is rolling and then will total the sum of all the rolls. The problem is that the output for the random number generator is two separate lists and I can't figure out how to either make them one list and then sum the one list or how to sum the two lists. Any help is welcome. Thanks! (p.s. this is the code I have so far)

```
def d20(number):
   for i in range(int(input("How many dice are your rolling?: "))):
      x = [random.randint(1,20)]
      x = x.append(x)
      #print(x)
  #print(sum(x))
```

d20(2)

Comment: You create a *new* list inside the loop.

Comment: Create the list outside of the loop and `append()` to it instead of creating a new list each loop iteration.

Comment: You're also reusing `x` for two things: to hold the list and to hold the new die.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a variable to store the total as its calculated.
Just make sure the total is outside the for loop.

Like this:

```
def d20():
    total = 0
    for roll in range(int(input("How many dice are you rolling?: "))):
        total += random.randint(1,20)
    return total
```